Flutter:flutter_libserialport: ^0.4.0 the max write bytes is 60?
I need to write 120 bytes of data through the serial port, but I found that I can only successfully write 60 bytes using the write interface of the flutter_libserialport library. Is there any way to solve this problem?
The following is my code
debugPrint(
        "Send command: ${request.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0').toUpperCase()).join(' ')}");
debugPrint("length: ${_portManager.write(request)}");


class SerialPortManager {
  final String portName;
  late SerialPort _serialPort;
  final LogManager logManager; // 添加 LogManager 成员

  SerialPortManager(this.portName, this.logManager) {
    _serialPort = SerialPort(portName);
    _serialPort.config = SerialPortConfig()
      ..baudRate = 115200
      ..setFlowControl(SerialPortFlowControl.none);
  }

  bool open() {
    if (!_serialPort.openReadWrite()) {
      try {
        _serialPort.open(mode: SerialPortMode.readWrite);
        return true;
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint("Error opening port $portName: $e");
        logManager.addLog("Error opening port $portName: $e");
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  void close() {
    if (_serialPort.isOpen) {
      _serialPort.close();
    }
  }

  int write(Uint8List data) {
    try {
      if (!_serialPort.isOpen) {
        if (!open()) {
          return -1;
        }
      }
      return _serialPort.write(data);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error writing to port $portName: $e");
      logManager.addLog("Error writing to port $portName: $e");
      return -1;
    }
  }

  Stream<Uint8List>? listen() {
    try {
      return SerialPortReader(_serialPort).stream;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error setting up listener for port $portName: $e");
      logManager.addLog("Error setting up listener for port $portName: $e");
      return null;
    }
  }
}


the print is :

flutter: Send command: 4C 4B 00 7C 2F 40 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 12
flutter: length: 60

I want to use serial to write more than 60 bytes in Flutter

The Dart library wraps the C library, which offers blocking and non-blocking writes. According to https://sigrok.org/api/libserialport/unstable/a00021.html the blocking write will always send all the bytes unless timeout occurs. The non-blocking write returns what ever it feels like. To use the blocking write, supply the optional timeout parameter. It seems you have two choices: let the library loop for you, but expect to be blocked, or loop yourself. Use logic of the form "I wanted to send 120 but only the first 60 were sent, so I have another 60 to go, wait a bit and try sending the rest"

Oh, your suggestion is very useful. I tried to modify the timeout value in the write method to make it a blocking call, and then I can successfully send instructions over 60 bytes.

int write(Uint8List data) {
    try {
      if (!_serialPort.isOpen) {
        if (!open()) {
          return -1;
        }
      }

      return _serialPort.write(data,timeout: 500);

    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error writing to port $portName: $e");
      logManager.addLog("Error writing to port $portName: $e");
      return -1;
    }
  }

/// Write data to the serial port.
  ///
  /// If `timeout` is 0 or greater, the write operation is blocking.
  /// The timeout is specified in milliseconds. Pass 0 to wait infinitely.
  ///
  /// Returns the amount of bytes written.
  int write(Uint8List bytes, {int timeout = -1});

so I can change timeout to 0 or >0,and it works well now~
